# BIT(1) versus TINYINT(1) para valores booleanos

Tags: mysql, sql, modelagem

Posso estar enganado, mas tenho a impressão de que, na prática, o padrão em MySQL é utilizar colunas do tipo `TINYINT(1)` para armazenar valores booleanos, `true`/`false` ou `0`/`1`. Só que `TINYINT` acomoda até 1 byte de informação, o que não é necessário para valores booleanos. No SQL Server, sempre usei o tipo `BIT` para isso, mas no MySQL tenho dúvidas se isso é adequado. Aliás, o próprio MySQL Workbench mapeia `BOOL` e `BOOLEAN` como *aliases* de `TINYINT(1)`.

Existe algum problema em usar `BIT(1)` para valores booleanos? Se sim, qual? Se não, por que todo mundo usa `TINYINT`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) não há problema, pelo contrário.

> A bit-field type. M indicates the number of bits per value, from 1 to 64. The default is 1 if M is omitted

Aí diz que pode guardar de 1 a 64 bits.

No passado `BIT` era um alias para `TINYINT` mas não é mais. Coisa de maluco, né? `BOOL` continua sendo alias de `TINYINT`.

O tamanho mínimo de armazenamento de uma coluna do tipo `BIT` é 1 byte, mesmo que só precise de 1 bit. [Se tiver várias colunas, haverá uma otimização aproveitando o mesmo byte](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html) para acomodar até 8 colunas em cada byte armazenado. Então tem vantagem em usá-lo.

Há quem recomende não usar porque não é fácil manipulá-lo corretamente. Então usar um tipo numérico normal seria melhor já que o ganho de espaço geralmente é desprezível. Não tenho experiência suficiente para afirmar, mas não me parece ser tão difícil usá-lo corretamente. Pelo menos se a pessoa tiver um mínimo de noção de como tratar este tipo de dado e ler a documentação antes de fazer uso dele, como deve fazer com qualquer coisa em desenvolvimento de software. Mas também não vejo um ganho tão grande em usá-lo, pode haver em certos cenários que estoura a página por pouca coisa. Quase ninguém pensa em otimizações nesse nível.

Me parece que `BIT` tem a semântica mais baixo nível e `BOOL` mais alto nível, marcando *status*. Em geral em banco de dados, me parece que, semanticamente, há pouca necessidade do uso do `BIT`.

Claro que o o `BOOL` ou `TINYINT` pode aceitar valores diferentes de 0 e 1 se não fizer alguma outra restrição por conta própria.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md)

Comment: Estou marcando esta resposta como aceita por se referir diretamente ao uso de BIT para representar valores booleanos, mas recomendo fortemente a leitura da [resposta do @Bacco](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108849).

Answer (score 6):

O tipo `BIT` foi feito com **bitfields** em mente, e não bits "avulsos". Não que você não possa guardar um bit só, mas não ha economia de espaço neste caso.

Uma coluna `BIT(1)` vai ocupar um byte por linha, assim como uma coluna `BIT(8)`. Uma coluna `BIT(64)` vai ocupar 8 bytes. Uma coluna `BIT(59)` vai ocupar os mesmos 8 bytes, pois de qualquer forma, não caberiam 59 bits em menos que 8 bytes.

O [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#idm140230913768192) define esta fórmula para estimativa de espaço:

> BIT(M) approximately (M+7)/8 bytes

De acordo com a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html), você pode ter um campo BIT com até 64 bits de comprimento.

Quanto à entrada e ao retorno de dados, há um *padding* que corresponde ao valor definido na coluna. Se você insere `0b011` numa coluna BIT(6), na verdade está inserindo `0b000011`. Ao ler o dado, receberá um valor de 6 bits de volta.

### Usando uma coluna BIT

Para usar colunas BIT literalmente, usa-se uma das duas sintaxes abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE t (b BIT(8));
INSERT INTO t SET b = 0b1010;
INSERT INTO t SET b = b'1010';
```

Os valores retornados são strings binárias, se precisar em formato numérico, pode forçar um *cast*:

```
mysql> SELECT b+0, BIN(b+0), OCT(b+0), HEX(b+0) FROM t;
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| b+0  | BIN(b+0) | OCT(b+0) | HEX(b+0) |
+------+----------+----------+----------+
|  255 | 11111111 | 377      | FF       |
|   10 | 1010     | 12       | A        |
|    5 | 101      | 5        | 5        |
+------+----------+----------+----------+
```

O [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-field-literals.html) tem mais detalhes sobre *literals*.

### Considerações

Há um [artigo](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/)<sup>en</sup> que menciona muitos bugs na implementação do tipo BIT, não sei o quanto está atualizado.

Adicionalmente, há uma discussão num [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9456) do MySQL que comenta que a coluna BIT só é implementada em MyISAM. Como é uma ocorrência de 2005, isto pode ter mudado.

Vale notar que o BIT tem um parente, que é o tipo SET, que é guardado bit a bit. O SET se parece com o ENUM, mas pode guardar vários valores simultaneamente (como tags, por exemplo). O SET está para o `checkbox` assim como o ENUM está para o `radiobutton`:

```
CREATE TABLE myset (col SET('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'));
INSERT INTO myset (col) VALUES ('A,D')
```

Neste exemplo, `A`, `B`, `C` e `D` ocupam um bit cada no banco. O `INSERT` acima estaria setando 2 destes bits.