# Qual a utilidade do tipo de coluna varchar(0)?

Tags: mysql

Vi uma pergunta sobre comprimento de coluna do tipo `Varchar` e fui consultar um livro que tenho e me deparei com a seguinte afirmativa: O comprimento máximo deve ser um número entre 0 a 255.

- Qual a utilidade do tipo de coluna varchar de comprimento zero?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

De acordo com o manual do *[MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html)*:

> O MySQL permite que você crie uma coluna de tipo `VARCHAR(0)`. Isso é útil
>   principalmente quando você precisa ser compatível com sistemas
>   antigos que dependem da existência da coluna, mas que não usam seu
>   valor. `VARCHAR(0)` Também é bastante agradável quando você precisa de uma
>   coluna que pode ter apenas dois valores: Uma coluna que é definida
>   como `VARCHAR(0) NULL` ocupa apenas um bit e pode ter apenas os valores
>   NULL e ' ' (string vazia).

Comment: Além de sistema antigos, qual a utilidade de ter uma coluna com valores NULL?

Comment: @Laerte Não entendi o questionamento. Essa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2296/quando-devemos-permitir-que-uma-coluna-de-uma-tabela-de-um-banco-de-dados-aceite) do bigown responde a sua pergunta? :)

Comment: Minha pergunta é mais relacionada a essa pergunta aqui mesmo, me pergunto qual a utilidade de ter uma coluna que aceita APENAS null e não as que aceitam valores nulos e valores normais.

Comment: Achei, não era especificamente sobre coluna zerada, mas a situação é análoga: Um varchar(0) com NULL ou não se comporta igual coluna BIT: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108842/70 - E só aproveita espaço se tiver mais de uma.

Answer (score 5):

Assim como o [@Marconi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/13322/marconi) já mencionou conforme a documentação, você pode ver da seguinte forma:

- Você precisa de apenas 1 bit;
- Uma maneira não ortodoxa de ter um `boolean`, com `NULL`/`' '` para `false`/`true`;
- Manutenibilidade de um sistema legado onde os valores não são mais necessários, mas é inviável efetuar um `DROP COLUMN`, pois poderia acarretar em uma série de problemas devido sua falta;

Isso não é padrão, mas o `MySQL` permite. No [`SQL SERVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms176089.aspx) por exemplo:

> char [ ( n ) ] Dados de cadeia de caracteres não Unicode de
>   comprimento fixo. n define o comprimento da cadeia de caracteres e
>   deve ser um valor de 1 a 8.000. O tamanho de armazenamento é n bytes.
>   O sinônimo ISO para char é caracteres.

Comment: Bela ampliação +1.