# Otimizando colunas de tabelas MySQL que recebem apenas dois valores diferentes

Tags: mysql, modelagem, tipagem

Possuo uma tabela em MySQL com 30 colunas, sendo que 25 podem receber apenas um dos seguintes valores: **Não** ou **Sim**. Atualmente elas estão definidas como `char(3)`.

Caso eu converta essas colunas de char para `tinyint`, recebendo os respectivos valores 0 ou 1, minhas queries se tornarão mais otimizadas? Enfim, qual seria o tipo de dados mais recomendado para esse caso?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108842/bit1-versus-tinyint1-para-valores-booleanos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caso eu converta essas colunas de char para `tinyint`, recebendo os respectivos valores 0 ou 1, minhas queries se tornarão mais otimizadas?

As *queries* não serão mais otimizadas porque, de forma geral, o tipo não cria otimizações, ainda mais se a comparação é com  tipos numéricos diferentes sendo usados. Claro que pode haver um pequeno ganho geral, não pela *query*, mas porque ocupando menos espaço haverá mais dados no cache e a carga pode se tornar mais eficiente em alguns cenários. Não é a *query* que fica melhor, e o ganho depende de questões que você não tem controle direto.

Só pra deixar claro, a escolha do tipo certo pode influenciar outros fatores, como o citado acima, e pode até dar o resultado certo ou errado. Não importa para esta questão, mas o que influencia o funcionamento do banco de dados é extremamente complexo e nem sempre fácil de prever, por isso o certo é sempre medir e não confiar em receitas de bolo que dizem o que é mais rápido (claro que medir corretamente é bem difícil, quem não se compromete a aprender tudo com profundidade terá que se contentar com a sorte).

> Enfim, qual seria o tipo de dados mais recomendado para esse caso?

Me parece ser esse mesmo, independente de otimização, procure usar o que for mais semanticamente adequado, em geral fará pouca diferença, mas de fato não parece ser interessante ter 3 caracteres para algo que só pode ser 2 valores com uma semântica booleana.

Pode tentar o tipo `BIT` também, em alguns casos pode dar um outro ganho, este parece ser um caso, mas para ter ganho é preciso saber usá-lo corretamente, o que não é tão simples e pode complicar a aplicação à toa se não precisa da otimização. Precisa colocar todos esses dados na mesma coluna, se usar uma coluna para cada dado o ganho não acontecerá.

Também poderia usar o tipo `BOOL` só para dar mais semântica, ele é só um apelido para `TINYINT`.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108842/bit1-versus-tinyint1-para-valores-booleanos

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelas informações.